# If browser width is greater that 1000px, show images

Tags: javascript, browser, width

Is it possible to get the width of the browser web view and act on it if it is greater than 1000px?

Example (in pseudocode):
If browser width is greater that 1000px;

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:1; visibility:visible;">
<img src="images/borderleft.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Modern Way: Media Queries

```
<div class="showWide">
<img src="images/borderleft.png">
</div>

// in your css file
.showWide {
   position:fixed; 
   top:0; 
   left:0; 
   z-index:1;
   visibility: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .showWide {
        visibility: visible;
     }
}
```

2011 Way: JQuery

```
// returns width of browser viewport
if( $(window).width() > 1000)
{
  //add or unhide image.
}
```

And for more information...[jquery width() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/).